# Stock Market API

Tags: api

I wondered if there was some stock market api that would allow me to create an indepenant website to display a certain corporation's stock info.

I've looked at Google Finance API and apparently you can only use it to make iGoogle gadgets so that won't work.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this as off topic. It's a question about the best API to use to solve a particular problem.

Comment: This is absolutely not off topic. Moderators are out of control.

Comment: @JZ too bad you're 3 years late :p

Comment: @jollypianoman just voted this to be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are incorrect about the [Google Finance API (no longer available)](https://developers.google.com/finance/). There is a Javascript API which you should be able to use in any ordinary web application.

Comment: hmm...I'll have to look into this more then. Thanks!

Comment: This is now deprecated and about to be shut down, unfortunately. For those looking for an alternative, there's another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api

Answer (score 22):

Yahoo actually does this quite well. They offer web services that you can get quotes from.

http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs

Comment: +1 - That's handy to know. Also, I love how the tutorial is hosted on a google domain.

Comment: I use their stock price history CSV API. It doesn't get updated with today's stock prices until like 9pm each night. Also it doesn't support realtime quotes. It also doesn't have fundamentals.

Comment: Seems like this API is [archived](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yahoo-finance-managed/). Has it moved elsewhere?